# MVC DateTime validation issue in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have MVC app with a custom login page. The model is generated by Entity Framework and it's called "User" .
When use logs in, the server code updates the login date: user.LoginDate = DateTime.Now;
And it works fine.

But now I started applying the validation. What I did is:
1) I created another class, made it partial and named User.cs:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
public partial class User
{
    [Bind]
    public class UserMetadata
    {
        [DisplayName("Email")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Email field is required")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }

        ...

        [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2010", "2/2/2024", ErrorMessage = "message")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LoginDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And now I have a problem. When EF tries to update the database, it throws an error about some kinda data validation issue in the code where I'm trying to update the LoginDate field.

If I comment this class, it works fine, no error, but no validation neither.

I thought that maybe it's datetime format, so I also tried the following attribute for a LoginDate field:

```
       [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
       [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss tt}")]
```

Also tried
           [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff}")]

However, it did not help and it's quite frustrating, because when I look at my database, I see that the LoginDate is written in the proper format:
2014-12-26 19:49:12.247

Please advise.

Comment: Why you need the validation of the `LoginDate`? This field is not user's input. Your own server code assigns correct values to it.

Comment: In most examples metadata class is external to the class which it describes, could that be a problem. Also, metadata properties are of object type. But I am only guessing here.

Comment: End perhaps you don't need metadata after all: http://www.remondo.net/entity-framework-code-first-data-annotations/

Comment: Mark, I don't really need to validate this field. The reason is the following: The User DB model has around 8 fields. My other user.cs class which I use for validation purpose only initially had only 2 fields where I put the attributes to validate. However I got an error when I tried to update the logindate field, so I decided that this is because my other partial user class missed validation attribute for the field I'm chanding

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed the problem. The solution is: I removed "[Bind]" attribute and now it works.